# writing function that calculate averge in below list

Tags: list, function, dictionary

in this list, I want to calculate the average between F & M and save its new list.

```
grade = [{'id':1, 'M':20 , "F":15},
 {'id':2, 'M':14 , "F":12}, 
 {'id':3, 'M':17 , "F":18},
 {'id':4, 'M':13 , "F":17.5}]
```

the output should be like this

```
ave_grade=[{"id":1 ,"average":17.5},{"id":2 ,"average":13},....]
```

how could I write a good function?

Answer (score 0):

```js
const grade = [{
  id: 1,
  M: 1,
  F: 10
}, {
  id: 2,
  M: 5,
  F: 10
}]
const avg = (...args) => args.reduce((acc, cur) => acc + cur, 0) / args.length
const ave_grade = grade.map(item => ({id: item.id, average: avg(item.M, item.F)}))

console.log(ave_grade)
```